# How to solve a problem using selenium on Ubuntu EC2 server with python script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ecs

I am trying to extract all data of column "Nb B" in this page : https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php')
url_links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'match/cotes-')]")))]

print(len(url_links), '\n')

nb_bookies = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@id and @role="row" ]/td[last()]'):
    nb_bookies.append(i.text)

nb_bookies = [float(i) for i in nb_bookies]
nb_bookies = np.array(nb_bookies)
print(nb_bookies, '\n')
```

When I run this code on a Ubuntu PC It works perfectly, I have this output :

```
24 

[12. 10. 12. 11. 11. 12. 12. 12. 12. 11. 11. 12. 11.  9. 12. 12. 12. 12.
 12. 12. 12. 12. 12. 12.]
```

but when I try on a EC2 Ubuntu server I have this output :

```
24

[2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2.]
```

Here is the config of my EC2 server : ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20200611 (ami-0a63f96e85105c6d3)

To solve this problem I deleted the 4 last line of code and add this line of code :

```
print([my_elem for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@id and @role="row" ]/td[last()]")))])
```

But I have a syntax error

Comment: For syntax error you can escape " characters . "//tr[@id and @role=\"row\" ]/td[last()]"

Comment: for syntax error your method works but when I run the script on a Ubuntu EC2 It does not give me the good output